# Python import from package file inside same directory

Tags: python, import, package

I'm trying to create my first [python package](https://github.com/josh-bone/sportsrefscraper), and I have a dicrectory structured like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
├── test_scrape.py
├── sportsrefscraper
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── games.py
│   ├── league.py
│   ├── players.py
│   ├── teams.py
|   ├── utils.py
|   └── ...
└── ...
```

I would think that I can import from utils inside teams.py, but when I run test_scrape.py

```
"""test_scrape.py
"""
import datetime as dt
from sportsrefscraper.players import scrape_game_logs, scrape_per100
from sportsrefscraper.games import scrape_boxscores, scrape_play_by_play, scrape_shot_chart
from sportsrefscraper.teams import get_roster
from sportsrefscraper.config import TEAMNAME_TO_ID, PLAYERS
import random

GAMES = [
        [dt.date(2023, 3, 4), 'PHI', 'MIL']
    ]

class TestScrape:
    
    def test_x(self):
        ...
```

I get this error

```
________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting test_scrape.py ________________________________________________________    
ImportError while importing test module '/<user>/Documents/sportsrefscraper/test_scrape.py'.
    Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
    Traceback:
    ../../miniconda3/envs/test_sportsref/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    test_scrape.py:5: in <module>
        from sportsrefscraper.teams import get_roster
    sportsrefscraper/teams.py:4: in <module>
        from utils import teamname_to_id
    E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had to add a . before my import to tell the Python Path which directory to find "utils" in.

In teams.py, I changed

```
from utils import teamname_to_id
```

to

```
from .utils import teamname_to_id
```

Comment: relative path ftw

Comment: the first is looking for a package named `útils`. unless you downloaded that with pip or something, chances are you won’t have it.

Comment: No, it was my own utils.py file. It appears in the file structure, and is in the same directory as "teams.py"